# Star (*) within Pandas boolean indexing

Tags: python, pandas, boolean-indexing

Because of a typo, I happened upon some Pandas DataFrame boolean indexing syntax that I'm not familiar with and I can't find any information describing what is actually happening.

I was trying to retrieve a dataframe based on two conditions with an `&` but typed a `*` instead and I was surprised to see that the results are the same

```
    ex1 = dist[(dist['token'].str.isalnum()) * (dist['count']>2000)]
    ex2 = dist[(dist['token'].str.isalnum()) & (dist['count']>2000)]

    ex1 == ex2
    # returns
    #     token  count
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
    #     True   True
```

Comment: Treat the True as 1 and False as 0 , so 1 * n = n . 0* n = n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

& is a bitwise logical operator, whereas * will cast booleans as real

You can get more details here
https://www.pyblog.in/programming/bitwise-operators-in-python/

Comment: Got it, Thanks! I personally like the python order of precedence better for the * than the &. Are there any disadvantages to using the real method?

Comment: Pandas relies on numpy, which uses [numexpr](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr)  to evaluate expressions (faster than python). Using * with booleans is not supported by numexpr, and it lets Python do the job.

I tried with a dataframe of 1e8 rows. By filtering based on 5 columns, using & was twice as fast.